# Cakephp send email 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm creating a user in cakephp. Everything is working BUT when I send email after creating user it shows 500 Internal Server Error. When I turned debug mode on, it shows following error.

```
Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 96 → SmtpTransport->_auth()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1161 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Plugin/Client/Controller/EmployeesController.php line 176 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → EmployeesController->add()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(EmployeesController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(EmployeesController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

My Code for sending email,

```
if (!empty($useremail)) {
   $Email = new CakeEmail("smtp");
   $Email->helpers('Html', 'Form', 'Text');
   $Email->emailFormat('html')
    ->template('Client.newuseraddition', '')
    ->subject('FIELDTASKS: New User Added')
    ->to($useremail)
    ->from('no-reply@fieldtasks.com', 'FIELDTASKS')
    ->viewVars(compact('useremail', 'link'))
    ->send('My message');
}
```

After this line

```
$Email = new CakeEmail("smtp");
```

I print `$Email` variable and it is printing successfully. But error occured on `send('My message')` function....
What is the issue here..Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always mention the _exact_ error message (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion). Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: The issue was with smtp username and password..I updated it and now emails are working..By the way I'm using cakephp 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with smtp username and password..I updated it and now emails are working..